# Storing NSData in app build-path with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, download, directory, nsdata, asihttprequest

I am using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to download tiles to be used in my MKMapView. Testing the code it downloads whatever I download into a NSData variable. (My files average 50mb) Note that this is basically almost the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729990/downloading-file-with-asihttprequest-iphone-app) unanswered question.

I have found that I can directly download the file from my webserver into a file e.g.:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/my_file.txt"];
```

For mapview I need the files in a folder called `Tiles` which is inside my app's build. It ends up in this directory:

> /var/mobile/Applications/887F4691-3B75-448F-9384-31EBF4E3B63E/MyApp.app/Tiles

Which I found out when I called:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tiles"]);
```

So what I am trying to do now is download these files (take note the plural) and put them in in the `Tiles` folder. To start with, I can either ZIP these images together to extract later on my device and place in the `Tiles` folder, or I can just go ahead and download all the images separately (which seems easier since I already know all the file-names)

I tried this piece of code and it gives me an error. It is in my mapview's `viewDidLoad` just before I load the tiles. *Take note it is only there for testing the download-code and will later be place somewhere else to be triggered by a button.*

Here is the code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://...my-website.../25.png"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tiles"]]; // THE PROBLEMATIC LINE
[request startSynchronous];
NSError *error = [request error];
if(!error)
{
    NSLog(@"Loaded Map");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error occured while loading map");
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```

And this appears in the console:

```
2011-06-26 21:12:09.651 MyApp[5309:707] Error occured while loading map
2011-06-26 21:12:09.669 MyApp[5309:707] Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=8 "Failed to delete file at path '/var/mobile/Applications/887F4691-3B75-448F-9384-31EBF4E3B63E/MyApp.app/Tiles'" UserInfo=0x184b20 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1d4ac0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to delete file at path '/var/mobile/Applications/887F4691-3B75-448F-9384-31EBF4E3B63E/MyApp.app/Tiles'}
```

**So how can I store the downloaded file in a directory on the iPhone where I can find and use it later?**

Thanks  for the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write directly into your application bundle. You should use a directory inside your app's sandbox, such as /Documents or /Library/Caches. See [Getting paths to standard application directories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW6) for how to get these paths.

Comment: Sweet thanks. All my effort and you solve the problem in a single paragraph! haha, thank you!